# Create XML with XPATH + SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I need to put something together like the following example that I detail below. This I have to do from my SQL query

Here example:

```
<Rooms>
  <Room id="1|30#30|23|2017-11-10|1|5453|5451|3|0|0" roomCandidateRefId="1" 
   code="1" description="Standard" nonRefundable="false"/>
</Rooms>
```

Here what I try

```
 select 
   n.c.value('(./@id)[1]','varchar(max)') as 'id',
   n.c.value('(./@roomCandidateRefId)[1]','int') as'roomCandidateRefId',                             
   n.c.value('(./@code)[1]','int') as 'code'
from @res.nodes('//Room') as n(c)
for xml path('Room'),root('Rooms')
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?
Thank you very much for your time.

Example complete:

```
<Options>
 <Option supplierCode="" type="Hotel" paymentType="MerchantPay" status="OK">
  <Rooms>
     <Room id="1|30|23|2018-012|0|0" roomCandidateRefId="1" code="39" 
     description="Individual" nonRefundable="true"/>
  </Rooms>
</Option>
  <Option type="Hotel" paymentType="MerchantPay" status="OK">
   <Rooms>
     <Room id="1|30|23|2018-01|0|0" roomCandidateRefId="1" code="39" 
    description="Individual" nonRefundable="true"/>
  </Rooms>
 </Option>
```

I want to get:

```
<Room id="1|30|23|2018-012|0|0" roomCandidateRefId="1" code="39" 
description="Individual" nonRefundable="true"/>
```

Comment: I don't get it... Are you trying to build the XML by a SQL query? Are you trying to read from an XML? What is `@res`? Where is the data coming from (table, variable, file upload, ...)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build (replicate) an xml using sql. I receive an xml that contains among other things the node Rooms, @res would be the variable in which I save xml that they send me, I need to get the complete node Room (save it as a variable and send it to another xml). All this from a stored procedure sql.
Sorry, if I was not clear

Comment: So: There is some XML coming in with many Rooms and you want to pick one room and create a new XML with this? Correct? Is the incoming XML oft the same structure or entirely different? Please provide a (reduced) example of your input XML and the needed output you'd expect.

Comment: Yes, they send many Rooms. I want to get the Room node in a variable and then add it in another XML.
In the main post I leave the complete example and the result I want.
Thank you

Comment: npalle, see my updated answer. You did not tell anything about your second step (*add it to another XML*), but I'd suggest to start a new question with this - if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is a mix of **creating XML** and **reading from XML** (with a tendency to *reading from*).

But according to your question's title you want to **create** the XML. If my magic crystal ball works well, you'd need this:

```
DECLARE @rooms_mockup TABLE(id VARCHAR(100),CandidateRefId INT,Code INT, Descr VARCHAR(100),NonRefundable BIT);
INSERT INTO @rooms_mockup VALUES('SomeID 1',1,1,'Description for 1',1)
                               ,('SomeID 2',22,22,'Description for 2',0);
SELECT r.id AS [@id]
      ,r.CandidateRefId AS [@roomCandidateRef]
      ,r.Code AS [@code]
      ,r.Descr AS [@description]
      ,r.NonRefundable AS [@nonRefundable]
FROM @rooms_mockup AS r
FOR XML PATH('Room'),ROOT('Rooms');
```

The result

```
<Rooms>
  <Room id="SomeID 1" roomCandidateRef="1" code="1" description="Description for 1" nonRefundable="1" />
  <Room id="SomeID 2" roomCandidateRef="22" code="22" description="Description for 2" nonRefundable="0" />
</Rooms>
```

### Hint:

The id value `1|30#30|23|2017-11-10|1|5453|5451|3|0|0` looks like a clear *1.NF breaker*. This can be okay with exported data, but is bad with the physical storage within an RDBMS's table...

### UPDATE

According to you updated question you want to get one `<Room>` out of an XML with many rooms:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Options>
 <Option supplierCode="" type="Hotel" paymentType="MerchantPay" status="OK">
  <Rooms>
     <Room id="1|30|23|2018-012|0|0" roomCandidateRefId="1" code="39" 
     description="Individual" nonRefundable="true"/>
  </Rooms>
</Option>
  <Option type="Hotel" paymentType="MerchantPay" status="OK">
   <Rooms>
     <Room id="1|30|23|2018-01|0|0" roomCandidateRefId="1" code="39" 
    description="Individual" nonRefundable="true"/>
  </Rooms>
 </Option>
 </Options>';
```

--My example uses a variable with the room's id to get one specific room:

```
 DECLARE @id VARCHAR(100)='1|30|23|2018-012|0|0';
 SELECT @xml.query(N'/Options/Option/Rooms/Room[@id=sql:variable("@id")]');
```

--If your surroundings may vary, you can use a *deep search*

```
 SELECT @xml.query(N'//Room[@id=sql:variable("@id")]')
```

Hope this helps...